# The effect displayed by SKShapeNode is different from that of CAShapelayer

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, skshapenode

I am going to use SKShapeNode to display a Bezier curve graph, but the displayed effect is very strange, and it is not the same as the one displayed by CAShapeLayer. I don't know what is wrong. Does anyone know the problem?

Here is a screenshot of the effect I showed in two different ways.

[The effect displayed by CAShapeLayer looks normal and is as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqRvt.png)

[the effect displayed by SKShapeNode misses some lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF9n3.png)

here is my main code:

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 54.5, y: 244.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 54.5, y: 164.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 53.5, y: 243.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 29.5, y: 201.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 54.5, y: 70.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 79.5, y: 127.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 54.5, y: 70.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 227.5, y: 70.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 227.5, y: 164.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 227.5, y: 70.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 254.5, y: 127.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 227.5, y: 244.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 200.5, y: 201.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 227.5, y: 244.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 54.5, y: 244.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 227.5, y: 244.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 55.5, y: 245.5))
bezierPath.close()


let scene = SKScene.init(size: CGSize.init(width: 300, height: 300))
scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.contentView.presentScene(scene)

let node = SKShapeNode.init()
node.path = bezierPath.cgPath
node.lineJoin = .miter
node.lineCap = .round
node.miterLimit = 10
node.strokeColor = SKColor.blue
node.fillColor = SKColor.red
node.lineWidth = 10
node.isAntialiased = true
scene.addChild(node)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code should work for you -- adding the path elements in a clockwise direction

```
let N:CGFloat = 300 //box size
let C:CGFloat = 20 //control offset

let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:N*0.5),
                    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:C, y:N*0.15),
                    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:C, y:N*0.35))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:N),
                    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:-C, y:N*0.65),
                    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:-C, y:N*0.85))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:N, y:N))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:N, y:N*0.5),
                    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:N-C, y:N*0.85),
                    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:N-C, y:N*0.65))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:N, y:0),
                    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:N+C, y:N*0.35),
                    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:N+C, y:N*0.15))
bezierPath.close()
```